# Moving the Edit Text

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` which is laid out in a `Framelayout`. I am trying to allow the `EditText` to be movable around the screen when selected.

Hence, whenever the user selects the mode which allows moving of items, I will set the edit text enabled(false), this works by removing the possibility of having edit text to get focus and show up the blinking cursor or the softkeyboard. But at the same time, I cannot receive any touch input when I attempt to move it.

Is there any solution of which I will be able to move the edit text and not having the edit text to receive focus?

I tried setting the `focusable` or `focusableInTouchMode` to false, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by two settings. First you need to have your wrapper structure (LinearLayout) handle the move events. Hook this to your wrapper's Touch event:

```
void FrameTouch (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Move) {
        int placeX = (int)e.Event.GetX () - v.Width / 2;
        int placeY = (int)e.Event.GetY () - v.Height / 2;
        v.Layout (placeX, placeY, placeX+v.Width, placeY+v.Height);
    }

}
```

Then you need to override your EditText's onTouch event to make sure it doesn't swallow the touch events while it is disabled:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
{
    if (!Enabled) 
        return false;

    base.OnTouchEvent (e);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the EditText in it's own layout (like a LinearLayout), that way you can have the touch events react from the layout instead of the EditText.

Comment: yeah, for now, it's wrapped in a layout. but when I hit within the parameters of the edit text it gets the focus and the blinking cursor comes in and softkeyboard appears.

Comment: look at `setFocusableInTouchMode()` to disable the focus for your EditText, that way the LinearLayout should take the focus instead.

Comment: i think with this the softkeyboard does come out, but the cursor will say nothing to paste.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a FrameLayout may not be the right choice:

> All child elements of the FrameLayout are pinned to the top left corner of the screen; you cannot specify a different location for a child view. [(from docs)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)